Ender 3 v2 with CR Touch suddenly refuses to home Z-axis
I see some similar questions have been asked but can't see one that describes my problem.
In a nutshell the printer won't home from the Z-axis home position, which it needs to do to commence printing.
I have had the printer for nearly 18 months and about 12 months ago I fitted the CR Touch sensor. I had no troubles at that time. But today, each time I tried to get a print started it failed at the initial homing step of the print run.
I have tried reinstalling BLTouch firmware with no change in status. I reinstalled the original firmware, and the printer would home using the limit switches in all 3 axes. I reinstalled the CR Touch firmware, and the problem was back—the printer would home in the X and Y axes, but in the Z-axis, the printer raised the gantry to the start position but failed to lower to detect the bed using the CR Touch, instead simply clicking the probe in and out a few times before quitting.
If I use the Z-axis move to raise the gantry higher, to 100 mm for example, home all works successfully with the probe successfully finding the bed and homing correctly. From this position (home all) the initial print step of homing fails. Raising the gantry before commencing the print does not work as the unit changes the Z-position to "0" from the actual raised position and fails to home as if it had already been homed.
I don't seem to be able to find help on the web with this issue beyond re-installing firmware which I have done. The Z-axis limit switch works when homed without the CR Touch add-in, so that does not seem to be the problem.

Check the cables and or replace the sensor. With Z switch it works, so it must be the sensor or the cables connecting it.

Thanks for the reply. I had checked cables and wondered about the sensor, but it was the gantry that wouldn't move the sensor into range. After a couple of days unplugged, I went through the usual prep again and now it starts fine. I note that the Z-position number is now something like 4.59 instead of 0. I had noted a similar resetting of Z-position 100 to 0. I had tried position the nozzle as close as possible to the plate and setting that as home, but as soon as it went through the homing process in the print process, it reset it to 0. Just one of those things a few days off fixed, I guess.
